# Trigger REST API POST call on Field/Object Update

Tags: trigger, rest-api, push

Beside Salesforce, I have an external AWS DynamoDB table in place, mirroring some information of the business relationships stored in Salesforce.
Currently, I retrieve the information with a time-driven job on AWS, calling a Salesforce GET query in a AWS Lambda.

Is there a possibility in Salesforce to activate a trigger which calls REST API POST in order to push the any changes (on change) on Salesforce objects/fields to the AWS database?

UPDATE

https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/event-driven-salesforce-change-datacapture-joe-pugh/

That's what I am looking for.

Comment: Are you detecting changes on Salesforce Objects / Fields or record?

Comment: I try to find a way to detect changes on Objects / Fields. I guess using triggers could be a way to do. The trigger should then call REST API POST request containing the changes in order to update the database on AWS side. If possible without APEX programming.

Answer (score 2):

Callouts aren't supported in triggers, however, you can call `@Future(Callout=true)` method ([docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_future.htm)) or enqueue class that implements `System.Queueable, Database.AllowsCallouts` ([docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_queueing_jobs.htm)) with necessary information about updated records and make POST request there.

You can also create Process in Process builder on fields change and call Apex method with `@InvocableMethod(callout=true”)` annotation ([docs](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_apex_flow_flag_invocable_methods_callouts.htm&release=230&type=5)).